# How to mutate some object properties without Typescript errors?

Tags: typescript, mutation, zod

This question is not `Zod`-related but I'm using this library to handle my TS types.
Considering the super-simplified schema below:

```
export const Event = z
  .object({ 
    ... 
    subtype: z.array(z.enum(['abc', 'def', 'ghi']),
    ...
  })

export type Event = z.infer<typeof Event>
```

For whatever the reasons are, I'd like to modify an `event` object like below:

```
export const stringify_event = (event: Event) => {
  event.subtype = event.subtype.join(',')    <-- Type 'string' is not assignable to type...
  return event
}
```

...and I don't understand how to get rid of the TS error. How to "mutate" my event? Thanks.

**-- EDIT --**

I've made a [MRE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEBuFzIN4BQyxycA%20gNYQCeAXMiAK4C2ARtANxElwgD2YABbRKNegEEoUONQA8AZzBRQAcwB8BAL4ECCPiEWkQZCNnD0MZsMgC8%20bsXJU6yAIwAaB0YHCoolwDaAETiyIrKICpB7sgh-EIi4apBALpaOgD0GcgAQhAIcIzyKKgA5MzIRarIAMoAigAyqJBoyAUg8WFgfFAoAAZwUjJ9yAAUnfKMAA5TPZAAJgCUnllhfK0gEBDzyN1t%20thQ1gmkQ9TIoHtwXREqwDDA26fS1Dp6BtZTvVODECZWZBgPTI8gAjgAbYAtOyjUw4MAWLDwxa2NT2EjIOHgAB0vB8ImctkxVlx8V8-mxACs%20KBRqV3KVFl5emBGFAQMT4eldPp5HxwRBseC%20CpRkEAEoQSbghGxGJfCA-Xr-eGA4FgyGQUa8FXgRaLIA) to illustrate my problem.

The reason I want to "mutate" a property is because I use `SQLite` which doesn't allow `array`. So before saving an event I need to make it `SQLite`-compatible.

Comment: Could you share an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: If you want, for whatever the reasons are, use `subtype` to store *either* arrays or strings, just label it like that using [unions](https://zod.dev/?id=unions).

Comment: How is `'abc'|'def'|'ghi'` valid TypeScript? It should say that you can't use bitwise-or on strings...

Comment: Please don't cut off the error. I'm **guessing** that it the cut off part is "number", which would make sense... given that the type of `subtype` is an array of numbers.

Comment: ... and yes, z.enums should receive an array of supposed values, not result of binary OR.

Comment: @l-_-l Done ! I hope it make the question clearer.

Comment: @raina77ow Your right ; it was in bad pseudo-code also. I've updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Zod is ouside of my scope. But it seems that you have a `z.union` method,
You could set the property `subtype: z.union([z.array(z.enum('abc'|'def'|'ghi')), z.string()]` in your Event object.

I guess in the typesctipt side the property subtype would be typed as ["abc" | "def" | "ghi"] | string,

[MRE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEBuFzIN4BQyxycA+gNYQCeAXMiAK4C2ARtANxElwgD2YABbRKNegEEoUONQA8AZzBRQAcwB8yAD7JFykCoIBfAgQR8Qi0iDIRs4ehjthkAXnzdi5KnWQBGADQeVgLCUKI+ANoAROI6SqpR-sgx-EIiugkAukYmAPS5yABCEAhwjPIoqADkzMjlqsgAygCKADKokGjIpSCpcXxQKAAGcFIyQ8gAFH3yjAAOcwOQACYAlIH5OnxdIBAQy8hg22Yg2FDOaaRj1MigR6RxeirAMMD7V9LUJieWc4NzowgNicZBgAzI8gAjgAbYCdNyTWw4MAOLDI1auDSEEjIJHgAB0vBCIm8rimeLAhNSoXCpHkyEknwU8X0alW+IAVnxQJMqv4qqsgoMwIwoCBcU4cqZzPI+NCIPjoXwVJMogAlCCzaEo5JJP4QAGDYHI0HgqGwyCTXjG8CrVZAA) with a property `Array<string> | string`

Comment: How would this play in with the Zod schema? I'd rather just make two separate types.

Comment: @NCAC : I've updated my question with a MRE and making it Zod-agnostic. However, I do not understand your code, It seems (to me a TS newbie) super complicated for something "simple" (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not mutate the object but create a new one, because they should be different kind of thing:

```
interface IEventSQL {
    a_key: number;
    another_key: string
}

const prepare_event_for_sqlite = (event: IEvent): IEventSQL => {
    return {
        a_key: event.a_key,
        another_key: event.another_key.join(',')
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you mix them together (e.g. define `another_key` to `string[] | string`) you will need to use type guard everywhere to ensure it is `string[]` or `string` and that is annoying

---

If you want to reuse this pattern, a utility type will be help:

```
type ToSQL<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? string : T[K]
}

type IEventSQL = ToSQL<IEvent>
```

The type `ToSQL` will convert all `Array` props to `string` and keeps remains the same.

Comment: If my object has much more than 2 properties (a_key, another_key), is it possible to use de/restructuring to make IEventSQL interface equals IEvent interface except for some key? Thks.

Comment: you can extends the `IEventSQL` with `Pick<IEvent,"a_key" | "OTHER_KEY_TO_KEEP">` or `Omit<IEvent, "another_key" | "OTHER_KEY_UNWANT">` and redefine those different keys

Comment: and I just edit the answer with another approach that convert all `Array` without redefine manually